# Formatting of Timer in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, timer, formatting

I have written a code to run a macro in VBA. Now that I'm nearing the end of the project, I'd like to have a timer indicate the total time.

I'm using this for the timer code:

```
Sub Clock()

    Dim startTime As Double, endTime As Double
    startTime = Timer

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox endTime - startTime

End Sub
```

The problem i've run into is I don't know how to format this code into the rest of the code. The entire project is made up of 9 subs, each with a Sub/End sub start and finish.

How can I place the clock code into the rest of this code successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: I usually do something like this: `MsgBox Format(TimeSerial(0, 0, endTime - startTime), "hh:mm:ss")`. This takes the total seconds and converts it into the time format. In terms of where, you want this in the initial/primary sub that starts the process. This would be the one that calls all the other subs. You need to put the starttime before all the code starts and the endtime at the end then show the msgbox.

Comment: @Simon I'm getting the same error, where it's requesting the initial Sub have an End Sub.

Laid out like this:
Sub Part_1()
'
' Part_1 Macro
    
    Sub Clock()

    Dim startTime As Double, endTime As Double
    startTime = Timer

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox endTime - startTime
    
    
    
'0.75- Fix number formatting of QUOTE-DATE column.
    With Range("P2:P5000")
    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
     .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
End Sub

Comment: Don't declare date/time variables as _Double_. _Date_ it should always be.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've put in your comment looks like it has a sub within a sub.
This will always cause an error.  You can call a sub from another sub, but you can't embed a sub within a sub like this.

Sub within a sub:

```
'Will never work
Public Sub SomeProcedure()

    Public Sub SomeOtherProcedure()
        MsgBox "Some message"
    End Sub

End Sub
```

Sub calling another sub:

```
'Will work
Public Sub SomeProcedure()
    SomeOtherProcedure
End Sub

Public Sub SomeOtherProcedure()
    MsgBox "Some message"
End Sub
```

For your code timing I use this method:

```
Public StartTime As Double 'Place at very top of module.

Public Sub MainProcedure()

    RunTimeStart 'Place at start of each procedure you're timing.

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
    
    MsgBox "Code ran in " & RunTimeEnd & " seconds.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Code Timer" 'Place at end of each procedure you're timing.

End Sub

Public Sub RunTimeStart()
    StartTime = Timer
End Sub

Public Function RunTimeEnd() As Double
    RunTimeEnd = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Darren. That does the "Public" part before the Sub and Function denote?

Comment: The functions/variable are available to all modules.